# RegEx for removing everything before and after a delimiter

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am trying to remove everything before and after two `|` delimiters using regex.

An example being:

```
EM|CX-001|Test Campaign Name
```

and grabbing everything except `CX-001`.  I cannot use a substring as the number of characters before and after the pipes may change.

I tried using the regex `(?<=\|)(.*?)(?=\-)`, but while this selects `CX-001`, I need to select everything else but this.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following regular expression:

```
(^[^|]*\|)|(\|[^|]*$)
```

```
    String input = "EM|CX-001|Test Campaign Name";

    System.out.println(
        input.replaceAll("(^[^|]*\\|)|(\\|[^|]*$)", "")
    );  // prints "CX-001"
```

Explanation of the regular expression:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^|]*                    any character except: '|' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \|                       '|'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \|                       '|'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^|]*                    any character except: '|' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only 2 pipes in you string, you could either match upon the first pipe or match from the last one until the end of the string:

```
^.*?\||\|.*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^.*?\|` Match from start of string non greedy until the first pipe
- `|` Or
- `\|.*$` Match from last pipe until end of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DtOcxF/1)

Or you might also use a negated character class `[^|]*` without the need of capturing groups:

```
^[^|]*\||\|[^|]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DtOcxF/2)

**Note**

In your pattern `(?<=\|)(.*?)(?=\-)` I think you meant that the last positive lookahead should be `(?=\|)` instead of the `-` if you want to select between 2 pipes.

Answer (score 0):

- Find: `^[^|]*\|([^|]+).+$`
- Replace: `$1`